# Is there something deeper behind the "verb classes swapping" of the subjunctive endings?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, conjugación, historia

In Spanish (and also in Latin, and most of Romance languages, too) the present **subjunctive** is formed by a kind of **swapping** the indicative **endings** between the verb declension classes: the 1st class (-a-) takes the indicative endings from the 2nd class (-e), and the 2nd and 3rd class (-i-) take the indicative endings from the 1st class:

[image]

**QUESTION**: Is it only coincidental, or is there something deeper behind it? Something like "as the subjunctive often expresses uncertainty, let's make the verbs sound weird by deliberately using a wrong set of endings to emphasize that we are not sure"?

It's clear that nowadays the endings are just inherited from the language history, but is there any theory about the origin of this particular coincidence?

Comment: It's the first time I've seen this, my guess is it has to do with the evolution of latin to spanish, but I don't know...

Comment: @PabloSaudiBombsYemen: It works very similarly in Latin, too. So the idea of "swapping the endings" is more or less **copied** from Latin.

Comment: it was just speculation as I dont know latin hahaha. I'm willing to know the answer...

Comment: @PabloSaudiBombsYemen: Am I correct in interpreting your sentence "It's the first time I've *seen* this" as "It's the first time I've **realized** (noticed) this"? So you as a (supposedly) native Spanish speaker have not been aware of it until now?

Comment: Yes, even I'm a native speaker it's the first time I've noticed this

Comment: I think @HonzaZidek 's comment is a pretty good answer.

Comment: @RobertoTomás: but I think that my comment is like the "argument" if creacionists - they feel happy they had "explained" the existence of the world by moving the problem one level back to the creator :-) Of course the Spanish *inherited* it, but how had it been felt in Latin then?

Comment: Well well, now this is an **interesting question!**. I look forward to the answer.

Comment: I never thought to question this.  I pretty much just accepted it at face value when my high school Spanish teacher showed us in class.

Comment: It probably has more to do with vowel harmony / apophony that overtime in Proto Italic or early, and thence due to other factors (like surrounding consonants, etc) assimilated into different vowels that happened to result in complementary distribution.  But that's speculation on my part, we don't have the evidence to support it because Proto Italic is not attested.  We need to see the development happen to give a definitive answer, and we can't.

Comment: My answer is speculative, so keeping it as comment.

As Spanish kept a small number of conjugation types (like most modern Romance languages) it may look like a swap to us. But Latin had five conjugation types.

According to [this](http://ocw.uv.es/ocw-secundaria-2/verbo_latino_II.pdf), Latin had just one thematic vowel of choice for the present subjunctive of *all* regular conjugation types. This vowel happened to be -a- but also happened to prove cacophonic in the 1st conjugation, which also had a thematic -a- of its own. The change to -e- in just that case had euphonic reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is what I have understood from the linked sources without me being a linguist:

[PIE had two different moods to express things that are not real](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/iedocctr/ie-ling/mood.html): subjunctive (non-factual or depending on a condition) and optative (wish).

Italic languages (among which, Latin) [merged both functions into one](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~jasanoff/pdf/Origin%20of%20Italic%20imperfect%20subjunctive.pdf).

The new Latin subjunctive mood was (normally) constructed using the optative forms, leaving what was the PIE subjunctive to express future now.

For some reason (which I haven't found), [the optative thematic vowel *-i-* was replaced by an *-a-* in Italo-Celtic languages](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~rnoyer/courses/51/PIEVerbs.pdf).

This is speculation, but I feel like all five Latin conjugations would have had an *-a-* thematic vowel for the subjunctive... If it weren't for the first indicative already having one. The way this was resolved was using *-e-* for the first conjugation and I guess some standard euphony rule took place there.

Of the five Latin conjugations, we inherited just three (like in Catalan, French and Italian; others, like Romansh and Romanian, kept four).

So the situation that once just looked like a rule with one exception now looks like some sort of vowel swap, but that's just a matter of perspective:

```
                      12345 Conjugation
Latin:   Indicative:  AEIII (2nd pers. sing. thematic vowel)
         Subjunctive: EAAAA
Spanish: Indicative:  AEE
         Subjunctive: EAA
```

I must insist, I'm not a linguist and haven't dug deeply in the linked documentation; but, as requested in the above comments, this may serve as a starting point to discuss.

Comment: It sounds plausible! The textbooks usually teach you to create subjunctive by *swapping* the thematic vowels, thus obfuscating the reason *why* it is like this.

Comment: Maybe the stem *a* **resisted** the shift of optative *i* to *a*, resulting in *a+i* which (as is not uncommon) merged to *e*.